# Need some help in creating a query in SQL?

Tags: postgresql

```
ID|message| UpdateTime| TicketID| StaffID

10008;"Yes, it is!";"2012-04-15 16:15:00";1008;660
10013;"Thanks for swift reply!";"2012-04-15 17:15:00";1008;660
```

CAn u tell me when I write these 2 queries :

```
Select MAX(UpdateTime) from TicketUpdate where ticketUpdate.id = 10008;    
Select MIN(UpdateTime) from TicketUpdate where ticketUpdate.id = 10008;
```

The output the same even in my database if have 2 different times.
Can u tell me what could be the problem here?

Comment: Possible dup of your earlier questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192521/need-some-help-in-creating-a-query-in-sql and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207362/need-some-help-in-creating-a-query-in-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ID` appears to be the unique identifier for this table.  Instead, it looks like you want to use `TicketID` to find the max and min values per ticket.

For example, to find them for `TicketID = 1008`:

```
SELECT MAX(UpdateTime) FROM TicketUpdate WHERE TicketUpdate.TicketID = 1008;    
SELECT MIN(UpdateTime) FROM TicketUpdate WHERE TicketUpdate.TicketID = 1008;
```

Or in one query:

```
SELECT 
  MAX(UpdateTime) AS newest,
  MIN(UpdateTime) AS oldest
FROM TicketUpdate
WHERE TicketID = 1008;
```

To get the most recent and oldest for every individual TicketID, use a `GROUP BY` and omit the `WHERE` clause.:

```
SELECT 
  TicketID,
  MAX(UpdateTime) AS newest,
  MIN(UpdateTime) AS oldest,
FROM TicketUpdate
GROUP BY TicketID
```

If you query using `ID`, you will always get the same row since there appears to be only one value for each `ID` that uniquely identifies its row.