# Need some help in creating a query in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 following tables :

```
Ticket(ID, Problem, Status,Priority, LoggedTime,CustomerID*, ProductID*);
TicketUpdate(ID,Message, UpdateTime,TickedID*,StaffID*);
```

Here is a question to be answered:

Close all support tickets which have not been updated for at least 24 hours. This will be records that have received at least one update from a staff member and no further updates from the customer (or staff member) for at least 24 hours.

My query is:

```
UPDATE Ticket SET Status = 'closed' FROM TicketUpdate 
WHERE(LoggedTime - MAX(UpdateTime))> 24 
     AND Ticket.ID = TicketUpdate.TicketID;
```

When I run this query on mysql it says that "<" does not exist.

Can you tell me  is my query right to for calculating the records which have not been updated for at least 24 hours and if it is right what should I do use instead of "<"?

Comment: What data type is the UpdateTime column? Is it a datetime, or a timestamp?

Comment: Possible duplicate of your earlier questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195759/need-some-help-in-creating-a-query-in-sql and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192521/need-some-help-in-creating-a-query-in-sql

Comment: Why would you mention MySQL, when the question is tagged PostgreSQL? Can be solved with window functions in PostgreSQL but not in MySQL, which does not support this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... records that have received at least one update from a staff member and
>   no further updates from the customer (or staff member) for at least 24
>   hours.

So, effectively, the last update must have been done by a staff member and be older than 24 hours. That covers it all.

(BTW, you have a typo: `TickedID` -> I use `ticketid` here.)

```
UPDATE ticket t
SET    status = 'closed'
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (1)
           ticketid
          ,first_value(updatetime) OVER w AS last_up
          ,first_value(staffid)    OVER w AS staffid
    FROM   ticketupdate
    -- you could join back to ticket here and eliminate 'closed' ids right away
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY ticketid ORDER BY updateTime DESC)
    ) tu
WHERE  tu.ticketid = t.id
AND    tu.last_up < (now()::timestamp - interval '24 hours')
AND    tu.staffid > 1 -- whatever signifies "update from a staff member"
AND    t.status IS DISTINCT FROM 'closed'; -- to avoid pointless updates
```

Note that PostgreSQL folds [identifiers to lower case](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) if not double-quoted. I advise to stay away from mixed case identifiers to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with postgreSQL then this should work

```
UPDATE Ticket SET Status = 'closed' FROM TicketUpdate 
WHERE abs(extract(epoch from LoggedTime - MAX(UpdateTime))) >24
     AND Ticket.ID = TicketUpdate.TicketID;
```

Comment: I cannot use DATEDIFF as I don't have column day.The data type for UpdateTime is timestamp

Comment: cannot use aggregate function in UPDATE
LINE 2: WHERE abs(extract(epoch from LoggedTime - MAX(UpdateTime)))